# jQuery: Using .each to cycle list

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a very simple list that contains images I need cycled. Here is the script:

```
var graphic = $('#banner li');
  graphic.hide();
    cycle = $(graphic).each(function(i,e) {
      while(i-- >= 0){
        $(e).show(300).delay(2000).hide(300)
      }
      if(i===0){cycle()}
    })
```

It almost works.. it shows all images instead of 1 at a time, but removes each one as it goes through the list. I could use `overflow:hidden;` in my CSS but I don't want that. It also doesn't repeat when it gets to 0.

Please help. I don't want the bloated cycle plugin either for such a simple task. Thanks!

**I tried making `graphic` into an array but I couldn't get that to work either.

[The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmZGC)

Comment: `cycle()` doesn't make much sense, it's an object not a function...

Comment: I was just trying to reference the function. Original script was wrapped in `animateBanner()`. I cannot reference with `cycle()`?

Comment: On a side note you don't need `$(graphic)` - `graphic` already IS a jQuery object; just use `graphic.each(...`.

Comment: Tried wrapping with extra function like (now deleted) answer said. http://jsfiddle.net/nmZGC/2/ Still does not work.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy good point. It originally had `#banner li` and I just didn't delete it.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand what your code is doing. Check if refactored version helps http://jsfiddle.net/nmZGC/3/

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/3Unbg/1/ - it isn't perfect but it only shows one image at a time and recalls itself at the end.

Comment: In fact you may find it pollutes the browser with timeouts so you'd want to call this only when the last element is showing

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy Pretty neat glitching though. Would make a cool effect barring errors.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté That works, thanks! Had something similar at one point but was trying with `.each` instead of `.eq` - didn't even know about `.eq`! Thanks again.

Comment: I would fix it myself but I'm sick at the moment so don't exactly have the concentration span to do so.. good luck getting this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactored your logic a bit using [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
var graphic = $('#banner li').hide(), //hide and cache list items selector
    i = 0,
    l = graphic.length;
(function cycle() {
    graphic.eq(i++ % l).show(300).delay(2000).hide(300, cycle);
}());
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nmZGC/3/)

By passing the IIFE itself as a callback we make the show, delay and hide loop repeat for the next item once the current iteration's `.hide()` animation completes.

You can increment the `i` at the end of the function and call `graphic.hide()` before entering the IIFE which some may consider more readable:

```
var graphic = $('#banner li'),
    i = 0,
    l = graphic.length;
graphic.hide();
(function cycle() {
    graphic.eq(i % l).show(300).delay(2000).hide(300, cycle);
    i++;
}());
```

The above is just for readibility purposes, it has the same effect as the first snippet.